# Google Script Copy created the copy in my folder and not original shared folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm very new to scripting, and I'm having an issue with the copy function, as well as finding newer relevant information.

My end goal is to copy a google workbook in a shared folder to another shared folder with a new name.

Currently I am simply trying to copy the workbook to a new name in the same folder, but the script puts it in my folder and not the shared.

Below is the very simple script I had written. If I do the copy manually through the google sheet copy function, I can put the newly named sheet anywhere. I tried to record these steps as a macro, but that did nothing.  As an FYI the Dfolder and Cfolder variables are the names of shared folders.  The function is to place the copied workbook in one of these 2 folders depending upon a cell value.

```
function MakeCopy() {
  let Dfolder = "Defect PreTrips"
  let Cfolder = "Clean PreTrips"
  let SheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let Truck = SheetName.getRange("E3").getValue();
  SheetName.getRange("C3").setValue(new Date());
  Tday = SheetName.getRange("C3").getDisplayValue();
  if (Truck != "")
    {
      SheetName.copy("Pretrip " + Truck + " " + Tday);
      ClearSheet();
    }
    else 
    {
      Browser.msgBox("Truck required");      
    }
};
```